# How to scroll using the SL4A Python interpreter?

Tags: android, python

I have SL4A installed on my Android phone (HTC Desire) and the Python interpreter. It works correctly but with a really annoying issue. I can find no way to scroll the interpreter output. I have it configured to buffer 1000 lines of output but scrolling using the optical trackball or by dragging on the touchscreen results in a stream of control characters being output on the screen.

E.g. scrolling up outputs this:

> > > ^[[6~^[[6~^[[6~^[[6~

Scrolling down outputs this:

> > > ^5[[~^5[[~^5[[~^5[[~

Does anyone know what might be causing this or how I can fix it?